# Haskell class functions: very confusing error

Tags: haskell

I have a very confusing error in a piece of my code. I was using the Data.Aeson package. I don't think this is a bug of the package.

```
class ToArrayFormat a where

    getObjects :: (ToJSON b) => a -> b

    toArrayFormat :: a -> Value
    toArrayFormat a = toJSON $ getObjects a
```

This piece of code will fail to compile with the error message :

```
    Could not deduce (ToJSON s0) arising from a use of ‘toJSON’
from the context (ToArrayFormat a)
  bound by the class declaration for ‘ToArrayFormat’
  at <interactive>:(103,1)-(108,43)
The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
In the expression: toJSON
In the expression: toJSON $ getObjects a
In an equation for ‘toArrayFormat’:
    toArrayFormat a = toJSON $ getObjects a
```

I'm very confused now. `getObjects` returns a `ToJSON b` instance which can be consumed by `toJSON` in `toArrayFormat`. Can't you deduce the instance of `b` from my `getObjects` definition? Why does it say `ToJSON s0` is ambiguous?

Comment: A slight deflection, though it's related: I suspect you will find it difficult to implement `getObjects` (try it!). When you understand why, I think you will also understand this error. (...in particular, I suspect you believe the type of `getObjects` says that the person writing an instance of the class picks an instance of `ToJSON`; but it in fact says that the person calling `getObjects` gets to pick the instance.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is this part:

```
The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
```

Note that `toJSON` has type:

```
toJSON :: ToJSON b => b -> Value
```

Also, this declaration:

```
getObjects :: (ToJSON b) => a -> b
```

says that `getObjects` can convert `a` into *any* type `b` which is in the `ToJSON` class. For instance, if `blah` is a value of type `a`, you could legally ask for:

```
getObjects blah :: Int
getObjects blah :: String
getObjects blah :: Char
```

and convert `blah` into an Int, String or Char since all of those are in the `ToJSON` class. That's probably not what you had in mind, nor what your `getObjects` function does.

To understand the error message, the problem is that in the expression `toJSON $ getObjects a`, GHC doesn't know how to type `getObjects b` - which member of the `ToJSON` class should it be - an Int?, String?, Char?, some other type?

You could specify a concrete type like this:

```
toArrayFormat a = toJSON $ (getObjects a :: Char)
```

but, like I've said, that's probably not what you had in mind.